# Looking for an alternative to Autosync or FolderSync apps. An app that will backup Google Docs to a local folder on Android

Tags: android, offline, file-synchronization, google-drive

I am looking to automatically sync my Google Docs in Google Drive to a local folder on my Android device.  Unfortunately, as some of you may know, Google Drive's offline setting is completely unreliable.

So, the next thing I tried was downloading Autosync/FolderSync apps to backup my Google Doc files to a local folder.  This would have worked great, but unfortunately an error pops up in both apps complaining "Google Doc files are not real files and cannot be downloaded".  Well, sure, this may be true, but Google Drive gives an option to download Google Doc files as PDF, text, and so on.  So there must be some app out there that can actually sync my Google Docs into a local folder right?

One idea I had was to convert all my Google Doc files into text files.  I suppose this could work, but first I must ask if there is an app that does what I'm looking for in the first place.